# Wifi Printing in android is not working

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi

I have made an android app for printing pdf file using printer which is connected to wifi. I have tried as per below code, Its only searching for the devices but nothing is happened. Please see my code and tell me what changes should I do to solve my problem. Any inputs will be appreciated!

**code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int pageHeight;
    public int pageWidth;
    public PdfDocument myPdfDocument;
    public int totalpages = 4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
        Context context;

        public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;

        }

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
                PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle metadata) {
            myPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);

            pageHeight = newAttributes.getMediaSize().getHeightMils() / 1000 * 72;
            pageWidth = newAttributes.getMediaSize().getWidthMils() / 1000 * 72;

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }

            if (totalpages > 0) {
                PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(
                        "print_output.pdf").setContentType(
                        PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).setPageCount(
                        totalpages);

                PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
                callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
            } else {
                callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onWrite(final PageRange[] pageRanges,
                final ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                final CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                final WriteResultCallback callback) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalpages; i++) {
                if (pageInRange(pageRanges, i)) {
                    PageInfo newPage = new PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth,
                            pageHeight, i).create();

                    PdfDocument.Page page = myPdfDocument.startPage(newPage);

                    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                        callback.onWriteCancelled();
                        myPdfDocument.close();
                        myPdfDocument = null;
                        return;
                    }
                    drawPage(page, i);
                    myPdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                }
            }

            try {
                myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(destination
                        .getFileDescriptor()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
                return;
            } finally {
                myPdfDocument.close();
                myPdfDocument = null;
            }

            callback.onWriteFinished(pageRanges);
        }

        private boolean pageInRange(PageRange[] pageRanges, int page) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pageRanges.length; i++) {
                if ((page >= pageRanges[i].getStart())
                        && (page <= pageRanges[i].getEnd()))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page, int pagenumber) {
            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

            pagenumber++; // Make sure page numbers start at 1

            int titleBaseLine = 72;
            int leftMargin = 54;

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(40);
            canvas.drawText("Test Print Document Page " + pagenumber,
                    leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);

            paint.setTextSize(14);
            canvas.drawText(
                    "This is some test content to verify that custom document printing works",
                    leftMargin, titleBaseLine + 35, paint);

            if (pagenumber % 2 == 0)
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            else
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

            PageInfo pageInfo = page.getInfo();

            canvas.drawCircle(pageInfo.getPageWidth() / 2,
                    pageInfo.getPageHeight() / 2, 150, paint);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public void printDocument(View view) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

        printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(this), null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this [Android-wifi-print - GitHub](https://github.com/SureshCS-50/Android-wifi-print). I have created a demo application for printing..
This is my flow.! which will help you a bit.

With the help of following links I have created this.

- [Link for learning Print job](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Custom_Document_Printing_Tutorial)
- [Link for learning WiFi Configuration and Switching](http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-accespoints-and-connect-to-them)

This is the flow of that prototype.

1. checks connectivity.
2. If connected in WiFi.. am storing that WiFi configuration.
3. Now checking whether I already have printer's information (WiFi configuration of WiFi printer) is available or not. If available, I'll scan and get list of WiFi ScanResults and connects to that else.. It'll showing list of WiFi and clicking on that, user will connect to printer and stores that WiFi configuration for future printing jobs.
4. After print job completes, I'm connecting to my previous WiFi or Mobile data connection.
5. Now going back to 2nd step.
6. If user connected in Mobile data, I'm just enabling WiFi and following 3rd step.
7. After Print job completes, I'm just disabling WiFi. so that, We'll be connected back to Mobile data connection. (That is android default).

If you want to print a file just call **print(file)** in **PrintUtility.class**
Following class will take care of all printing jobs..

```
public class PrintUtility implements Observer {

    private static final int TIME_OUT = 10000;
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIME_OUT = 5000;

    private Activity mActivity;
    private Fragment mFragment = null;

    private WifiConfiguration mPrinterConfiguration;
    private WifiConfiguration mOldWifiConfiguration;
    private WifiManager mWifiManager;
    private WifiScanner mWifiScanner;
    private List<ScanResult> mScanResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();

    private PrintManager mPrintManager;
    private List<PrintJob> mPrintJobs;
    private PrintJob mCurrentPrintJob;

    private File pdfFile;
    private String externalStorageDirectory;

    private Handler mPrintStartHandler = new Handler();
    private Handler mPrintCompleteHandler = new Handler();
    private Handler mWifiConnectHandler = new Handler();
    private String connectionInfo;

    private boolean isMobileDataConnection = false;

    private PrintCompleteService mPrintCompleteService;

    //    Observer pattern
    private Observable mObservable;


    public PrintUtility(Activity mActivity, WifiManager mWifiManager, WifiScanner mWifiScanner) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mWifiManager = mWifiManager;
        this.mWifiScanner = mWifiScanner;
        mPrintCompleteService = (PrintCompleteService) mActivity;
        mObservable = ObservableSingleton.getInstance();
        mObservable.attach(this);
    }

    public PrintUtility(Activity mActivity, Fragment mFragment, WifiManager mWifiManager, WifiScanner mWifiScanner) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mFragment = mFragment;
        this.mWifiManager = mWifiManager;
        this.mWifiScanner = mWifiScanner;
        mPrintCompleteService = (PrintCompleteService) mFragment;
        mObservable = ObservableSingleton.getInstance();
        mObservable.attach(this);
    }

    public void downloadAndPrint(String fileUrl, final String fileName) {

        new FileDownloader(mActivity, fileUrl, fileName) {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

                if (!result) {
                    mObservable.notifyObserver(true);
                } else {

                    // print flow will come here.

                    try {
                        externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        File folder = new File(externalStorageDirectory, Constants.CONTROLLER_PDF_FOLDER);
                        pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        mObservable.notifyObserver(true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    print(pdfFile);

                }

            }
        }.execute("");
    }

    public void print(final File pdfFile) {

        this.pdfFile = pdfFile;

        // check connectivity info -> mobile or wifi.
        connectionInfo = Util.connectionInfo(mActivity);

        if (connectionInfo.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_MOBILE)) {
            // follow mobile flow.
            isMobileDataConnection = true;

            if (mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
                mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }

            mWifiManager.startScan();
            setScanResults(mWifiScanner.getScanResults());

            printerConfiguration();

        } else if (connectionInfo.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI)) {
            // follow wifi flow..

            // this will get current wifiInfo and store it in shared preference.
            Util.storeCurrentWiFiConfiguration(mActivity);

            printerConfiguration();

        } else {
            mObservable.notifyObserver(true);
        }

    }

    private void printerConfiguration() {

        // check printer detail is available or not.
        mPrinterConfiguration = Util.getWifiConfiguration(mActivity, Constants.CONTROLLER_PRINTER);

        if (mPrinterConfiguration == null) {
            // printer configuration is not available.
            // display list of wifi available in an activity

            showWifiListActivity(Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PRINTER);

        } else {
            // get list of wifi available. if printer configuration available then connect it.
            // else.. show list of available wifi nearby.

            boolean isPrinterAvailable = false;

            // scans nearby wifi..
            mWifiManager.startScan();
            setScanResults(mWifiScanner.getScanResults());


            // checks this wifi in scan result list..
            for (int i = 0; i < mScanResults.size(); i++) {
                if (mPrinterConfiguration.SSID.equals("\"" + mScanResults.get(i).SSID + "\"")) {
                    isPrinterAvailable = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrinterAvailable) {

                // connect to printer wifi and show print settings dialog and continue with print flow.
                connectToWifi(mPrinterConfiguration);

                // prints document.
                doPrint();

            } else {
                showWifiListActivity(Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PRINTER);
            }

        }
    }

    private void showWifiListActivity(int requestCode) {
        Intent iWifi = new Intent(mActivity, WifiListActivity.class);
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(iWifi, requestCode);
    }

    private void connectToWifi(WifiConfiguration mWifiConfiguration) {
        mWifiManager.enableNetwork(mWifiConfiguration.networkId, true);
    }

    public void doPrint() {

        try {
            // it is taking some time to connect to printer.. so i used handler.. and waiting for its status.
            mPrintStartHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    mPrintStartHandler.postDelayed(this, TIME_OUT);

                    if (mPrinterConfiguration.status == WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT) {
                        if (mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {

                            if (Util.computePDFPageCount(pdfFile) > 0) {
                                printDocument(pdfFile);
                            } else {

                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);

                                alert.setMessage("Can't print, Page count is zero.");

                                alert.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        switchConnection();
                                    }
                                });

                                alert.show();
                            }
                        }
                        mPrintStartHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Failed to connect to printer!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        switchConnection();
                        mPrintStartHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                    }
                }
            }, TIME_OUT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Failed to connect to printer!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switchConnection();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void printDocument(File pdfFile) {

        mPrintManager = (PrintManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        String jobName = mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

        mCurrentPrintJob = mPrintManager.print(jobName, new PrintServicesAdapter(mActivity, mFragment, pdfFile), null);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void completePrintJob() {
        mPrintJobs = mPrintManager.getPrintJobs();

        mPrintCompleteHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mPrintCompleteHandler.postDelayed(this, CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);

                if (mCurrentPrintJob.getInfo().getState() == PrintJobInfo.STATE_COMPLETED) {

                    // remove that PrintJob from PrintManager.
                    for (int i = 0; i < mPrintJobs.size(); i++) {
                        if (mPrintJobs.get(i).getId() == mCurrentPrintJob.getId()) {
                            mPrintJobs.remove(i);
                        }
                    }

                    // switching back to previous connection..
                    switchConnection();

                    // stops handler..
                    mPrintCompleteHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                } else if (mCurrentPrintJob.getInfo().getState() == PrintJobInfo.STATE_FAILED) {
                    switchConnection();
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Print Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPrintCompleteHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                } else if (mCurrentPrintJob.getInfo().getState() == PrintJobInfo.STATE_CANCELED) {
                    switchConnection();
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Print Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPrintCompleteHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                }

            }
        }, CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
    }

    public void switchConnection() {
        try {
            if (!isMobileDataConnection) {

                mOldWifiConfiguration = Util.getWifiConfiguration(mActivity, Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI);

                // get list of wifi available. if wifi configuration available then connect it.
                // else.. show list of available wifi nearby.
                boolean isWifiAvailable = false;

                // scans nearby wifi.
                mWifiManager.startScan();
                setScanResults(mWifiScanner.getScanResults());

                // checks this wifi in scan result list.
                for (int i = 0; i < mScanResults.size(); i++) {
                    if (mOldWifiConfiguration.SSID.equals("\"" + mScanResults.get(i).SSID + "\"")) {
                        isWifiAvailable = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isWifiAvailable) {

                    // connect to printer wifi and show print settings dialog and continue with print flow.
                    connectToWifi(mOldWifiConfiguration);

                    mWifiConnectHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mWifiConnectHandler.postDelayed(this, TIME_OUT);
                            if (mOldWifiConfiguration.status == WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT) {
                                if (mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {

                                    try {
                                        mObservable.notifyObserver(true);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    mWifiConnectHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, TIME_OUT);

                } else {
                    showWifiListActivity(Constants.REQUEST_CODE_WIFI);
                }
            } else {
                mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                mObservable.notifyObserver(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mObservable.notifyObserver(true);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getPrinterConfigAndPrint() {
        mPrinterConfiguration = Util.getWifiConfiguration(mActivity, Constants.CONTROLLER_PRINTER);
        doPrint();
    }

    public void setScanResults(List<ScanResult> scanResults) {
        this.mScanResults = scanResults;
    }

    public void onPrintCancelled() {
        switchConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        mObservable.detach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateObserver(boolean bool) {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateObserverProgress(int percentage) {

    }

}
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. I actually tried that first. but, In flow, handling WiFi Configuration part has some back and forth switching in steps.. so I posted snaps of written flow itself.

Comment: @ArtjomB. As per your words.. I removed that image flow with text.. and did some refactoring in my code and posted that.. :)