# Delphi Java Bridge - how to instance a class and call a method on it

Tags: java, delphi

I'm trying to use a `.jar` file in my Delphi project for Android. Unfortunately, there is no information on the Internet talking about this clearly.

I create the Bridge as Embarcadero wrote in their documentation about using Java2OP, and I got the `.pas` file. All I want to know is, how do I use the interface `JPrintUtilClass`? I don't know how this file works, or how to use it.

Here is the `.pas` file:

```pascal
unit SdkPrint;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.Bluetooth,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
// ===== Forward declarations =====

  Jprint_sdk_BuildConfig = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.BuildConfig
  JEscUtils = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.EscUtils
  JEscUtils_1 = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.EscUtils$1
  JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.SerialManager$OnDataReceiveListener
  JPrintUtil = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.PrintUtil
  JPrintUtil_1 = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.PrintUtil$1
  JPrintUtil_Singleton = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.PrintUtil$Singleton
  JSerialManager = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.SerialManager
  JSerialManager_1 = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.SerialManager$1
  JSerialManager_ReadThread = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.SerialManager$ReadThread
  JSerialManager_Singleton = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.SerialManager$Singleton
  JALIGN_MODE = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.enums.ALIGN_MODE
  JBARCODE_1D_TYPE = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.enums.BARCODE_1D_TYPE
  JFONT_ID = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.enums.FONT_ID
  JMODE_ENLARGE = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.enums.MODE_ENLARGE
  JOnPrintEventListener = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.interfaces.OnPrintEventListener
  JBitmapToByteUtils = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.util.BitmapToByteUtils
  JBitmapToByteUtils_1 = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.util.BitmapToByteUtils$1
  JBitmapToByteUtils_PAlign = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.util.BitmapToByteUtils$PAlign
  JByteUtils = interface;//com.example.print_sdk.util.ByteUtils
  JSerialPort = interface;//com.lcserial.www.SerialPort
  JSerialPortFinder = interface;//com.lcserial.www.SerialPortFinder
  JSerialPortFinder_Driver = interface;//com.lcserial.www.SerialPortFinder$Driver
  JSerialPortTool = interface;//com.lcserial.www.SerialPortTool
  JVector = interface;//java.util.Vector

// ===== Interface declarations =====

  Jprint_sdk_BuildConfigClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{4AF7C67A-A9C7-4D40-AC55-59A00B9F9037}']
    {class} function _GetBUILD_TYPE: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetDEBUG: Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetLIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function init: Jprint_sdk_BuildConfig; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property BUILD_TYPE: JString read _GetBUILD_TYPE;
    {class} property DEBUG: Boolean read _GetDEBUG;
    {class} property LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME: JString read _GetLIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/BuildConfig')]
  Jprint_sdk_BuildConfig = interface(JObject)
    ['{3EF30B8F-3139-41C1-A3E1-97FEA126AAEE}']
  end;
  TJprint_sdk_BuildConfig = class(TJavaGenericImport<Jprint_sdk_BuildConfigClass, Jprint_sdk_BuildConfig>) end;

  JEscUtilsClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{9E23270C-7339-4000-B628-36F5AB13F947}']
    {class} function esc_barcode_1D_print(P1: JString; P2: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_barcode_2D_print(P1: Integer; P2: Integer; P3: Integer; P4: JALIGN_MODE; P5: JString): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_barcode_height(P1: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_barcode_width(P1: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure esc_buffer_clear; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_char_bold(P1: Boolean): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_char_enlarge(P1: JMODE_ENLARGE): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_char_font(P1: JFONT_ID): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_default_print: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_enable_mark(P1: Boolean): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_enter_print: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_exit_unicode: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_feature_list: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_feed_paper(P1: Boolean; P2: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_init_print: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_length_get: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_lib_version: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_main_mark: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_no_paper_print_status(P1: Byte): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_open_one_vote_one_control(P1: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_print_align(P1: JALIGN_MODE): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_print_hri: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_print_languageList: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_print_left_margin(P1: SmallInt): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_print_line_space(P1: Boolean; P2: Byte): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_print_state: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_psam_info(P1: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_psam_send(P1: Integer; P2: TJavaArray<Byte>; P3: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_select_sensor_stop_print: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_set_black(P1: Integer; P2: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_set_concentration(P1: Integer): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_set_encode(P1: Byte): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_set_language(P1: Byte): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_set_sn(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_set_sn_end: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_test: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_text_print(P1: JString): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getEscBuffer: TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function init(P1: Integer): JEscUtils; cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/EscUtils')]
  JEscUtils = interface(JObject)
    ['{154063F4-5B7B-4A21-9B2B-2CA70F9D0861}']
  end;
  TJEscUtils = class(TJavaGenericImport<JEscUtilsClass, JEscUtils>) end;

  JEscUtils_1Class = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{CCEFF579-0236-4ED3-97C8-4BDFCE28377C}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/EscUtils$1')]
  JEscUtils_1 = interface(JObject)
    ['{263CB672-7EE1-4F22-9E10-16D8DDA2F77E}']
  end;
  TJEscUtils_1 = class(TJavaGenericImport<JEscUtils_1Class, JEscUtils_1>) end;

  JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListenerClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{A1E769AF-2EBA-4A18-9B09-2B5F75D3116E}']
    {class} procedure onDataReceive(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>; P2: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/SerialManager$OnDataReceiveListener')]
  JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{4CE95D9C-BC11-43A8-8D64-C9908138973A}']
  end;
  TJSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListenerClass, JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener>) end;

  JPrintUtilClass = interface(JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListenerClass)
    ['{197C02F8-45F1-4961-B34E-E714AD84E558}']
    {class} function _GetWIDTH_PIXEL: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _Getcheck_paper: Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} procedure _Setcheck_paper(Value: Boolean); cdecl;
    {class} procedure closeDev; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function esc_text_print(P1: JString): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure exitUnicode; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getClient: JPrintUtil; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getGbk(P1: JString): TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getInstance: JPrintUtil; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getOffset(P1: JString): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure getTemperature; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure getVersion; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function init: JPrintUtil; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure initPrinter; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure initSDK; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function isChinese(P1: JString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function isChinese(P1: Char): Boolean; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure onDataReceive(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>; P2: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure print(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printAlignment(P1: JALIGN_MODE); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printAutoEnableMark(P1: Boolean); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printBackPaper(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printBarcode(P1: JString; P2: Integer; P3: Integer); cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printBarcode(P1: JString; P2: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; P3: Integer; P4: Integer); cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printBarcode2(P1: JBitmap); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printBitmap(P1: JBitmap); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printBitmap2(P1: JBitmap); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printConcentration(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printDashLine; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printEnableCertificate(P1: Boolean); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printEnableMark(P1: Boolean); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printEncode(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printEndNumber; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printFeatureList; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printFontSize(P1: JMODE_ENLARGE); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printFourColumn(P1: JString; P2: JString; P3: JString; P4: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printGoToNextMark; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printImage(P1: JBitmap); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printLanguage(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printLargeText(P1: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printLine; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printLine(P1: Integer); cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printMarginLeft(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printNoBarcodeText; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printQR(P1: JBitmap); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printQR2(P1: Integer; P2: Integer; P3: Integer; P4: JALIGN_MODE; P5: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printStartNumber(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printState; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printTabSpace(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printText(P1: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printTextBold(P1: Boolean); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printThicken(P1: Boolean); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printThreeColumn(P1: JString; P2: JString; P3: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printTwoColumn(P1: JString; P2: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure printUnderscore(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure resetPrint; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function resetPsam(P1: Integer; P2: TJavaArray<Byte>): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function sendApdu(P1: Integer; P2: JString; P3: TJavaArray<Byte>): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure setEncoding(P1: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function setLocation(P1: Integer): TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure setPrintDefLineSpacing; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure setPrintEventListener(P1: JOnPrintEventListener); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure setPrintLineSpacing(P1: Byte); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure setPrintSpeed(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure setSocket(P1: JBluetoothSocket; P2: JString); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure showBarcodeHRI(P1: Boolean); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure sleep(P1: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property WIDTH_PIXEL: Integer read _GetWIDTH_PIXEL;
    {class} property check_paper: Boolean read _Getcheck_paper write _Setcheck_paper;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/PrintUtil')]
  JPrintUtil = interface(JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener)
    ['{F62A814D-3547-4B21-905D-C9624753E306}']
  end;
  TJPrintUtil = class(TJavaGenericImport<JPrintUtilClass, JPrintUtil>) end;

  JPrintUtil_1Class = interface(JRunnableClass)
    ['{8FD0FAD7-0D4A-4242-87DB-3E30B5FB2909}']
    {class} function _Getthis: JPrintUtil; cdecl;
    {class} function _Getvalsize: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function init(P1: JPrintUtil; P2: TJavaArray<Byte>; P3: Integer): JPrintUtil_1; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure run; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property this: JPrintUtil read _Getthis;
    {class} property valsize: Integer read _Getvalsize;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/PrintUtil$1')]
  JPrintUtil_1 = interface(JRunnable)
    ['{5E560D8E-9C5D-4F73-92D2-0543822C26C2}']
  end;
  TJPrintUtil_1 = class(TJavaGenericImport<JPrintUtil_1Class, JPrintUtil_1>) end;

  JPrintUtil_SingletonClass = interface(JEnumClass)
    ['{8A00925F-0E6C-4820-BA88-D8A9FAA4D66B}']
    {class} function _GetINSTANCE: JPrintUtil_Singleton; cdecl;
    {class} function valueOf(P1: JString): JPrintUtil_Singleton; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function values: TJavaObjectArray<JPrintUtil_Singleton>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property INSTANCE: JPrintUtil_Singleton read _GetINSTANCE;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/PrintUtil$Singleton')]
  JPrintUtil_Singleton = interface(JEnum)
    ['{F8B01F89-4515-4C9E-80AA-AD23F4756141}']
  end;
  TJPrintUtil_Singleton = class(TJavaGenericImport<JPrintUtil_SingletonClass, JPrintUtil_Singleton>) end;

  JSerialManagerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{93E1233C-BFD5-4A4F-AEF8-81AD41133888}']
    {class} function _GetBAUTRATE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetPATH: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function _Getextvcc: JString; cdecl;
    {class} procedure _Setextvcc(Value: JString); cdecl;
    {class} function _GetmOutputStream: JOutputStream; cdecl;
    {class} procedure _SetmOutputStream(Value: JOutputStream); cdecl;
    {class} function _GetmSerialPort: JSerialPort; cdecl;
    {class} procedure _SetmSerialPort(Value: JSerialPort); cdecl;
    {class} function _GetserialPortTool: JSerialPortTool; cdecl;
    {class} procedure _SetserialPortTool(Value: JSerialPortTool); cdecl;
    {class} function _GetsetSam: JString; cdecl;
    {class} procedure _SetsetSam(Value: JString); cdecl;
    {class} function Bytes2HexString(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>): JString; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure close; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function escCommand(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>): Boolean; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function escCommand(P1: JString): Boolean; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function escCommand(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>; P2: Integer): Boolean; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function getClient: JSerialManager; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getInputStream: JInputStream; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getOutputStream: JOutputStream; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function init: JSerialManager; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function open: Boolean; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function receivePsam(P1: TJavaArray<Byte>; P2: Int64): Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure setOnDataReceiveListener(P1: JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure startReadThread; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property BAUTRATE: Integer read _GetBAUTRATE;
    {class} property PATH: JString read _GetPATH;
    {class} property extvcc: JString read _Getextvcc write _Setextvcc;
    {class} property mOutputStream: JOutputStream read _GetmOutputStream write _SetmOutputStream;
    {class} property mSerialPort: JSerialPort read _GetmSerialPort write _SetmSerialPort;
    {class} property serialPortTool: JSerialPortTool read _GetserialPortTool write _SetserialPortTool;
    {class} property setSam: JString read _GetsetSam write _SetsetSam;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/SerialManager')]
  JSerialManager = interface(JObject)
    ['{DCBA525F-7998-455B-92E3-BAAA93D6F749}']
  end;
  TJSerialManager = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSerialManagerClass, JSerialManager>) end;

  JSerialManager_1Class = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{DBE7BCE2-AE43-4DC9-BC96-8C0292D0696C}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/SerialManager$1')]
  JSerialManager_1 = interface(JObject)
    ['{B2EB9959-6F2D-413C-9CAD-971E08400A3E}']
  end;
  TJSerialManager_1 = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSerialManager_1Class, JSerialManager_1>) end;

  JSerialManager_ReadThreadClass = interface(JThreadClass)
    ['{F130A205-F0BE-4DF5-A4BB-E089587F5944}']
    {class} function init(P1: JSerialManager; P2: JSerialManager_1): JSerialManager_ReadThread; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure run; cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/SerialManager$ReadThread')]
  JSerialManager_ReadThread = interface(JThread)
    ['{8B080BC4-4080-47ED-9D86-D0C87F833EF4}']
  end;
  TJSerialManager_ReadThread = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSerialManager_ReadThreadClass, JSerialManager_ReadThread>) end;

  JSerialManager_SingletonClass = interface(JEnumClass)
    ['{04AFBD2A-5EC3-4896-B143-D540D3FB8985}']
    {class} function _GetINSTANCE: JSerialManager_Singleton; cdecl;
    {class} function valueOf(P1: JString): JSerialManager_Singleton; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function values: TJavaObjectArray<JSerialManager_Singleton>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property INSTANCE: JSerialManager_Singleton read _GetINSTANCE;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/SerialManager$Singleton')]
  JSerialManager_Singleton = interface(JEnum)
    ['{3F2E8946-1CF2-4295-A93F-FBA4F91E66DD}']
  end;
  TJSerialManager_Singleton = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSerialManager_SingletonClass, JSerialManager_Singleton>) end;

  JALIGN_MODEClass = interface(JEnumClass)
    ['{DD57EF9B-D9BD-4800-B9E0-8DCF6CB20C6C}']
    {class} function _GetALIGN_CENTER: JALIGN_MODE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetALIGN_LEFT: JALIGN_MODE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetALIGN_RIGHT: JALIGN_MODE; cdecl;
    {class} function &Get: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function valueOf(P1: JString): JALIGN_MODE; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function values: TJavaObjectArray<JALIGN_MODE>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property ALIGN_CENTER: JALIGN_MODE read _GetALIGN_CENTER;
    {class} property ALIGN_LEFT: JALIGN_MODE read _GetALIGN_LEFT;
    {class} property ALIGN_RIGHT: JALIGN_MODE read _GetALIGN_RIGHT;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/enums/ALIGN_MODE')]
  JALIGN_MODE = interface(JEnum)
    ['{2E72216B-8E1A-4FB0-9A18-112C0077FE14}']
  end;
  TJALIGN_MODE = class(TJavaGenericImport<JALIGN_MODEClass, JALIGN_MODE>) end;

  JBARCODE_1D_TYPEClass = interface(JEnumClass)
    ['{964C5000-043A-4EC1-B98A-FEEBCE464B69}']
    {class} function _GetCODE128: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetCODE39: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetCODE93: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetEAN13: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetEAN8: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetITF25: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetUPCA: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetUPCE: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;
    {class} function &Get: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function valueOf(P1: JString): JBARCODE_1D_TYPE; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function values: TJavaObjectArray<JBARCODE_1D_TYPE>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property CODE128: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetCODE128;
    {class} property CODE39: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetCODE39;
    {class} property CODE93: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetCODE93;
    {class} property EAN13: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetEAN13;
    {class} property EAN8: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetEAN8;
    {class} property ITF25: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetITF25;
    {class} property UPCA: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetUPCA;
    {class} property UPCE: JBARCODE_1D_TYPE read _GetUPCE;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/enums/BARCODE_1D_TYPE')]
  JBARCODE_1D_TYPE = interface(JEnum)
    ['{71202FD9-B725-4FDF-8E31-2FFAB7C47186}']
  end;
  TJBARCODE_1D_TYPE = class(TJavaGenericImport<JBARCODE_1D_TYPEClass, JBARCODE_1D_TYPE>) end;

  JFONT_IDClass = interface(JEnumClass)
    ['{FFC9C28D-7FFD-4B8B-9BD6-AF5B94E03F74}']
    {class} function _GetFONT_ASCII_12x24: JFONT_ID; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetFONT_ASCII_9x17: JFONT_ID; cdecl;
    {class} function &Get: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function valueOf(P1: JString): JFONT_ID; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function values: TJavaObjectArray<JFONT_ID>; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property FONT_ASCII_12x24: JFONT_ID read _GetFONT_ASCII_12x24;
    {class} property FONT_ASCII_9x17: JFONT_ID read _GetFONT_ASCII_9x17;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/example/print_sdk/enums/FONT_ID')]
  JFONT_ID = interface(JEnum)
    ['{E952A2D8-831D-45C0-9856-1B5DE9E11C81}']
  end;
  TJFONT_ID = class(TJavaGenericImport<JFONT_IDClass, JFONT_ID>) end;

  JSerialPortToolClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{18F19FB3-9A40-422C-B9AD-F04076C51CCE}']
    {class} function _GetmSerialPortFinder: JSerialPortFinder; cdecl;
    {class} procedure closeSerialPort; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function getSerialPort(P1: JString; P2: Integer): JSerialPort; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function init: JSerialPortTool; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} property mSerialPortFinder: JSerialPortFinder read _GetmSerialPortFinder;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/lcserial/www/SerialPortTool')]
  JSerialPortTool = interface(JObject)
    ['{01A9F76E-F9DA-41FB-99F3-5A11D273A5D4}']
  end;
  TJSerialPortTool = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSerialPortToolClass, JSerialPortTool>) end;

  JVectorClass = interface(JAbstractListClass)
    ['{AF3067AC-4EA6-496A-9A93-E5D96BDDDECD}']
    {class} function init: JVector; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function init(capacity: Integer): JVector; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function init(capacity: Integer; capacityIncrement: Integer): JVector; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function init(collection: JCollection): JVector; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure add(location: Integer; object_: JObject); cdecl; overload;
    {class} function add(object_: JObject): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function addAll(location: Integer; collection: JCollection): Boolean; cdecl; overload;
    {class} procedure clear; cdecl;
    {class} function clone: JObject; cdecl;
    {class} function &contains(object_: JObject): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function elements: JEnumeration; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure ensureCapacity(minimumCapacity: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function hashCode: Integer; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function indexOf(object_: JObject): Integer; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function indexOf(object_: JObject; location: Integer): Integer; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function lastIndexOf(object_: JObject): Integer; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function lastIndexOf(object_: JObject; location: Integer): Integer; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function remove(location: Integer): JObject; cdecl; overload;//Deprecated
    {class} function removeElement(object_: JObject): Boolean; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} procedure removeElementAt(location: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function retainAll(collection: JCollection): Boolean; cdecl;//Deprecated
    {class} function size: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function subList(start: Integer; end_: Integer): JList; cdecl;
    {class} function toArray: TJavaObjectArray<JObject>; cdecl; overload;
  end;
 overload;
    function toString: JString; cdecl;
    procedure trimToSize; cdecl;
  end;
  TJVector = class(TJavaGenericImport<JVectorClass, JVector>) end;

implementation

procedure RegisterTypes;
begin
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.Jprint_sdk_BuildConfig', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.Jprint_sdk_BuildConfig));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JEscUtils', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JEscUtils));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JEscUtils_1', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JEscUtils_1));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialManager_OnDataReceiveListener));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JPrintUtil', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JPrintUtil));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JPrintUtil_1', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JPrintUtil_1));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JPrintUtil_Singleton', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JPrintUtil_Singleton));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialManager', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialManager));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialManager_1', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialManager_1));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialManager_ReadThread', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialManager_ReadThread));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialManager_Singleton', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialManager_Singleton));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JALIGN_MODE', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JALIGN_MODE));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JBARCODE_1D_TYPE', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JBARCODE_1D_TYPE));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JFONT_ID', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JFONT_ID));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JMODE_ENLARGE', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JMODE_ENLARGE));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JOnPrintEventListener', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JOnPrintEventListener));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JBitmapToByteUtils', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JBitmapToByteUtils));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JBitmapToByteUtils_1', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JBitmapToByteUtils_1));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JBitmapToByteUtils_PAlign', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JBitmapToByteUtils_PAlign));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JByteUtils', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JByteUtils));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialPort', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialPort));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialPortFinder', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialPortFinder));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialPortFinder_Driver', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialPortFinder_Driver));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JSerialPortTool', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JSerialPortTool));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('SdkPrint.JVector', TypeInfo(SdkPrint.JVector));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTypes;
end.
```

Comment: What is you underlying problem? Want to print something? Describe the environment. Maybe [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234595/wifi-printing-in-android-is-not-working) would help?

Comment: My Problem is how to call the class of the  "JPrintUtilClass" interface

Comment: What .jar file did you process?

Comment: printer jar SDK

Comment: "printer jar SDK" doesn't tell us anything unless you indicate who produced it, and/or where it is located

Comment: The SDK came with documentation tell which methods and description for them ,  http://svoton.com/a/PRODUCTS/Mobile_Terminal/Android_Mobile_Terminal/2021/0413/43.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JPrintUtilClass` interface is meant to represent the static methods/properties of the Java `PrintUtil` class, whereas the `JPrintUtil` interface is meant to represent the non-static instance methods/properties instead.  You need to use the `JavaClass` property of the generated `TJPrintUtil` Delphi wrapper class in order to access the static members of the Java `PrintUtil` class, eg:

```pascal
uses
  SdkPrint;

TJPrintUtil.JavaClass.useSomeMemberHere;
...
```

Based on your recent comment, a *correct* translation of the example you provided from the SDK documentation would look like this in Delphi:

```pascal
uses
  ..., SdkPrint;

var
  pUtil: JPrintUtil;
begin
  try
    pUtil := TJPrintUtil.JavaClass.getClient;
    pUtil.printState;
    pUtil.printAlignment(TJALIGN_MODE.JavaClass.ALIGN_LEFT);
    pUtil.printTextBold(false);
    pUtil.printTwoColumn(StringToJString('Time: '), StringToJString('2021-05-09 15:50:41'));
    pUtil.printTwoColumn(StringToJString('order number:'), StringToJString('1'));
    pUtil.printText(StringToJString('unit price'));
    pUtil.printThreeColumn(StringToJString('iphoneXII'), StringToJString('1'), StringToJString('4999.00'));
    pUtil.printThreeColumn(StringToJString('MAC PRO'), StringToJString('1'), StringToJString('4999.00'));
    pUtil.printTwoColumn(StringToJString('order amount:'), StringToJString('9998.00'));
    pUtil.printEndNumber;
  except
  end;
end;
```

However, this won't work in your case, because most of these `PrintUtil` methods are non-static instance methods, but the generated Delphi code from Java2OP that you provided is treating them all as static class methods instead. Which means Java2OP is not importing the JAR correctly.  This is actually a known issue, see the following bug reports:

[RSP-15473: Java2Op emits erroneous code](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15473)

[RSP-21462: Java2OP outputting Class declarations instead of procedures](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21462)

[RSP-24029: Regression in Java2OP so that instance methods are treated as class methods](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24029)

So, you will have to manually correct the mistakes in the generated code to move *only* the non-static instance methods/properties from the `JPrintUtilClass` interface to the `JPrintUtil` interface (and probably do the same for many of the other interfaces in the same unit).  Then the above code should work.

Comment: this is an example from the SDK : try 
 {
 PrintUtil pUtil = PrintUtil.getClient (); 
 pUtil. printState (); 
 pUtil.printAlignment (ALIGN_MODE.ALIGN_LEFT); 
 pUtil.printTextBold (false); 
 pUtil.printTwoColumn ("Time: ", "2021-05-09 15:50:41"); 
 pUtil.printTwoColumn ("order number:", "1"); 
 pUtil.printText ("unit price"); 
 pUtil.printThreeColumn ("iphoneXII", "1", "4999.00"); 
 pUtil.printThreeColumn ("MAC PRO", "1", "4999.00"); 
 pUtil.printTwoColumn ("order amount:", "9998.00"); 
 pUtil.printEndNumber ();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) { }
 }

Comment: Thank you , was great and it was really what you explain and i deployed the .so file and working fine , thanks again